# Confused about bs4 imorting methods and their effect on attributes

Tags: beautifulsoup

I know versions of this question were asked in the past, but I'm still confused and would like to settle my doubts once and for all, if possible.

If I use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

my `soup` assignment is going to be

```
soup =  BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

If I do the importing thus:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
```

my `soup` assignment is

```
soup =  bs4(html, "lxml")
```

Finally, if I import using:

```
import bs4
```

my `soup` assignment is

```
soup =  bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Let's use a simple html and code:

```
html = """
<a href="some link" style="some style">Some Document</a>
"""
link = soup.select('a:contains(Document)')
```

Next, the main question:

```
type(link[0])
```

The output - in all three import cases - is:

```
bs4.element.Tag
```

But if I ask:

```
isinstance(link[0],bs4.element.Tag)
```

In the third case, I get `True`, but in the first two cases, I get

```
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'element'
```

Since the `select()` and `find_all()` methods frequently deliver both`Tag` or `NavigableString` results, I need to determine which is which using, for example, `isinstance()`. So in those cases, do I have to use the third import method? Why is there a difference in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a naming game you are doing. Lets go ahead and state that class `bs4.element.Tag` is the class of element instances.  Think of that as the absolute location of the `Tag` class in `bs4`. `bs4.element` represents the nested modules with `Tag` (which is found under the `element` module) being the class in  which the elements are instances of. When displaying the class info of those elements, it will always show `bs4.element.Tag`.

Now, with all of that said, you can access the `BeautifulSoup` object in different ways. And none of this changes the fact that element tags are of type `bs4.element.Tag`. When you import bs4:

```
import bs4
bs4.BeautifulSoup()
```

This imports the module under the module's default name `bs4`. And then you can access `BeautifulSoup` in that module with the dot notation as `BeautifulSoup` is a member of that module. But locally `bs4` is just a variable that references the `bs4` module.

When you import as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
```

`bs4` does not mean the same thing as the first example. In the first example we imported the entire module under its default name (`bs4`), but here we instead import the `BeautifulSoup` class and rename it **locally** as `bs4`. Regardless of what we call it locally, it is still a class at `bs4.BeautifulSoup`, where `bs4` is the module name. Locally though (local to this file), we created a variable reference to the `BeautifulSoup` class with a name that happens to be the same as the module.

So, when you use `select` to return elements, they are of the type `bs4.element.Tag`. This is true regardless of what your local variables happen to be named. This is internally how they are known.

So, when comparing `instance`, it is important to know, the variable name is not important, what is important is what the variable is referencing.  In the third example, `import bs4` causes `bs4` to reference the `bs4` module; therefore, `Tag` can be accessed at `bs4.element.Tag`.  But in the case where you use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4`, `bs4` no longer references the `bs4` module, it references the `BeautifulSoup` class which has no attributes called `element` with the attribute `Tag` as it is not a module but a class.

The local name is just how your current file is referencing the object it refers to.

So in your failing cases, you would need to import the `Tag` reference to a variable you can provide to `instance`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from bs4.element import Tag
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<div>Test<span>test</span><span>test2</span></div>')
>>> isinstance(soup.find('div'), Tag)
True
```

`Tag` here is just a name, but it references `bs4.element.Tag`, so it works.

We could call it anything and it will still work as long as it references the correct object:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from bs4.element import Tag as Apple
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<div>Test<span>test</span><span>test2</span></div>')
>>> isinstance(soup.find('div'), Apple)
True
```

Hopefully that makes more sense :).

EDIT: Just a tip, but `bs4` makes some references to things like `NavigableString` and `Tag` available in the top level module, so you don't have to reach all the way down to `bs4.element` to get a proper reference, you can simply do:

```
from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString
```

Again, this alternative reference of `bs4.Tag` is just a variable named `Tag` in the `bs4` module that refers to the actual `bs4.element.Tag` class. You can use that, and it will still refer to the same class. It is just used locally in the `bs4` module to reference the `Tag` class in `element`.

Comment: Thanks!  I will really have to wrap my head around this one! But I definitely learned something(s) new....